# Get access token from keycloak

Tags: angular, access-token, keycloak

I'm new to keycloak and Angular. In my angular 7  application, I'm using `angular-oauth2-oidc` to connect to keycloak. This is working as expected.

But **I want get the access token and store it in local storage**. Can someone help me to get it ?

*Login Function*

```
login() {
    this.oauthService.initLoginFlow();
  }

authConfig: AuthConfig = {
    issuer: "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/rpa",               
    redirectUri: window.location.origin + "/dashboard/process",    
    clientId: "spa-rpa",
    scope: "openid profile email offline_access rpa",
    responseType: "code",
    disableAtHashCheck: true,
    showDebugInformation: true
  };
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution by myself. I had to use an event listener as below.

```
this.oauthService.events
      .pipe(filter((e: any) => e.type === 'token_received'))

      .subscribe(() => {
        this.handleNewToken()
      },
      error => {
        console.log("Error : "+error);
      },
      () => {
        console.log('HTTP request completed.')
      }); 

private handleNewToken() {
    localStorage.setItem('Access_key', this.oauthService.getAccessToken());
    this.router.navigate(['/dashboard/process']);
    localStorage.removeItem("spinner_loading");
  }
```